# Google forms scripts to send email

Tags: google-forms

I have created a script to go along with a camp signup form. When I student signs up, I need an email sent to both the parent and the leader. I have the general script format correct as each one works when by itself (the script is bound to the spreadsheet, not the form). But if I have both functions in the code.gs file or in a separate file, neither of them work. How are we supposed to run more than one function attached to a form submission?

Here is my code for the two emails to be sent:

```
Here is my code for the two emails to be sent (if I add both these, it doesn't work):
function emailResponseToParent(e) {
var studentName = e.values[1];
var parentEmail = e.values[3];
var tripName = e.values[6]
var subject = "Your Young Life " + tripName + " registration has been submitted."
var message = "We have received " + studentName  + "'s signup registration for the "   + tripName  + ". More words here....";

MailApp.sendEmail(parentEmail, subject, message);
```

}

```
function emailResponseToLeader(e) {
var studentName = e.values[1];
var leaderEmail = "meg@me.com";
var tripName = e.values[6]
var subject = "A Young Life student of yours has signed up for " + tripName  + " camp."
var message = studentName  + "has just registered for " + tripName  + ". More words here....";

MailApp.sendEmail(leaderEmail, subject, message);
```

}

A separate question (less important) is how to create a script so that a later follow up email goes out based on a date (e.g. the week before camp starts).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be of any use but you can create a list of recipients to receive the SAME email (just like any email can specify multiple recipients). To do this replace your MailApp with the following:

var Emails = parentEmail + "," + leaderEmail;

MailApp.sendEmail(Emails, subject, message);

It has worked for me (but both recipients wanted the same info).

I couldn't get my script to access the form data until I came across the method used in your script (e.values[ ] ) which worked a treat - so thanks for that!